# Decision function problem based on the logistic function

Tags: logistic, decision-theory

Suppose we have a bunch of a sampled pairs $(x_1,y_1)...(x_n,y_n)$ with the $y_i =\pm1$.

Then consider the decision function $h(x) = -1$ if $p(x)=\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}\leq0.5$, and $h(x) = 1$ if $p(x) > 0.5$.  Where $p$ is interpreted, as per logistic regression, as the probability that $x\rightarrow +1$.  Then what is the probability that our decision function makes an inaccurate prediction?

For some reason I'm having a really hard time setting this problem up correctly.  It seems to me I want the area below the sigmoid curve to the left of the y-axis, and the area between the curve and the line $y=1$ to the right of the y-axis.  And then I need to somehow weight or normalize this integral so that it makes statistical sense.

Using the decision theory setup, I feel like this takes the form:
\begin{align}
&\int_{(-\infty,0]}p(x,y=1)dx + \int_{[0,\infty)}p(x,y=-1)dx\notag\\
=&\int_{(-\infty,0]}p(y=1\;|\;x)p(x)dx + \int_{[0,\infty)}p(y=-1\;|\;x)p(x)dx\notag\\
=&\int_{-\infty}^{0}\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}p(x)dx + \int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+e^{x}}p(x)dx\notag
\end{align}

However there is no mention of the distributions $p(x,y)$ or $p(x)$ (this is from a professor's notes and not from a book so that could have been an oversight).  Have I set this problem up correctly?  Or have I misinterpreted it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formulation is correct. Setting $\Lambda(x) \equiv \frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}$ and using the indicator function we can write

$$\int_{-\infty}^{0}\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}p(x)dx + \int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+e^{x}}p(x)dx = \\=\int_{\infty}^{\infty}p(x) \cdot \left(\Lambda(x)\cdot I_{\{x\leq 0\}} + [1-\Lambda(x)]\cdot[1-I_{\{x\leq 0\}}]\right)dx$$

$$=E_X\left(\Lambda(X)\cdot I_{\{X\leq 0\}} + [1-\Lambda(X)]\cdot[1-I_{\{X\leq 0\}}]\right)$$

and decomposing

$$=2\cdot E_X\left[\Lambda(X)\cdot I_{\{X\leq 0\}}\right] + 1 - P(X\leq 0) - E_X\left[\Lambda(X)\right]$$

The restricted and unrestricted expected value as well as the probability are estimable from the sample, without the need to specify the probability distribution of $X$.

For example

$$\hat E_X\left[\Lambda(X)\cdot I_{\{X\leq 0\}}\right] = \frac 1{n}\sum_{x_i\leq 0}\Lambda(x_i)$$

Comment: In your final decomposition, how are you able to pull the $I_{\{X\leq0\}}$ outside the expected value?  If it's by itself I understand it becomes $P(X\leq0)$, but in the first one it's multiplied by $\Lambda(X)$.

Comment: Small hours fatigue. I have corrected the expression.